# gnome-calendar doesn't sync Google Calendar Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, gnome-calendar

After upgrading Ubuntu to 20.04, `gnome-calendar` doesn't show the events in my Google Calendar, `gnome-contacts` does show the contacts which I have in Google services.

- Release: Ubuntu 20.04
- Package: gnome-calendar 3.36.0-1

Answer (score 4):

I've installed calendar via snap (Ubuntu Software) and it didn't work, so I've removed it and installed using apt and it works (there is gnome-calendar 3.36.1-1 in apt repo).

Use the following commands in terminal:

```
sudo snap remove gnome-calendar
sudo apt-get install gnome-calendar
```

Comment: I tried other suggestions in this question and this is the one that made it work. Thnaks!!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-calendar/+bug/1866999

- Importance: High
- ProblemType: Bug
- DistroRelease: Ubuntu 20.04
- Package: gnome-calendar 3.36.0-1
- ProcVersionSignature: Ubuntu 5.4.0-14.17-generic 5.4.18
- Uname: Linux 5.4.0-14-generic x86_64
- ApportVersion: 2.20.11-0ubuntu20
- Architecture: amd64
- CurrentDesktop: ubuntu:GNOME
- Date: Wed Mar 11 09:47:25 2020
- InstallationDate: Installed on 2018-02-23 (746 days ago)
- InstallationMedia: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS "Bionic Beaver" - Alpha amd64 (20180222)
- SourcePackage: gnome-calendar

Answer (score 2):

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the gnome calendar from the terminal and it still did not sync.  I had to remove my Google account completely in settings and add it again.  When I brought up Calendar it synced again.