# Ubuntu 20.04: my google account calendars have disappeared from GNOME calendar

Tags: 20.04, calendar, online-accounts

Not sure if the same problem as [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1236484/gnome-calendar-doesnt-sync-google-calendar-ubuntu-20-04). I have made a fresh installation of Ubuntu 20.04 and added my Google accounts in the Online Accounts of the Settings app.

At the beginning I could perfectly see all my calendars in the GNOME Calendar. But not sure what I might have installed that now the calendars are gone...

I think it happened right after installing the [Arc Menu](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1228/arc-menu/) extension, which required me to install the following dependencies as:

```
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extensions gnome-menus gir1.2-gmenu-3.0
```

So now I cannot see my Google calendars in GNOME Calendar anymore:
[image: pic1]

Even though all my online accounts are linked properly:
[image: pic2]

Any clue?

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness: when you click on the Google account, is the `Calendar` option switched on?

Comment: Yes everything switched on for  both Google accounts

Comment: Maybe Google needs renewal of your permission for Gnome to access your calendar. Try removing and re-adding your account.

Comment: Yep, first thing I did... rebooting, removing and re-linking accounts, uninstalling and re-installing gnome-calendar... nothing helps

Comment: Removing and adding the Google account back has actually caused my Google calendars to disappear from the Gnome Calendar.